# How can I get an image from url link and use it in HTML5 game, created in Flash?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, canvas

I have my HTML5 game created in Flash and I am trying to get image from link.
Let's say the image I want is at

`http://www.flooringvillage.co.uk/ekmps/shops/flooringvillage/images/request-a-sample--547-p.jpg`.

In my game I already have a `MovieClip` with instance name `pictureFromUrl`. So how do I set its image source the image found at the mentioned example page?

```
this.parent.pictureFromUrl = ??
```

Comment: "HTML5 game created in Flash" I'm having a hard time understanding what this means?

Comment: Flash CC and Animate CC allows you to create HTML5 Canvas projects

Answer (score 0):

To load images inside ActionScript 3 you use the Loader class.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
loader.load(new URLRequest("HERE GOES YOUR IMAGE URL"));

private function loadComplete(event:Event):void
{
     pictureFromUrl.addChild(loader.content);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why it returns the error **Loader is not defined**. I am mentioning that I run this game in browser NOT with .sfw extension, but in **HTML5 Canvas**. So this error appears in the browser's console